# Duplicate Record Found Error when Creating Entity

Tags: c#, duplicates, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

When creating an entity using the Xrm Tooling NuGet package, I receive the following error:

> Duplicate Record Found for Entity: [some entity type code] with ID: [some guid]

I am copying a bunch of attributes from another record in the same table (custom entity for which I'm splitting some records out into multiple records as part of a cleanup effort), including the primary field. However, there are no alternate keys defined for this particular entity and no duplicate detection rules enabled either.

Any idea why I'd be receiving this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me personally, this was because I forgot to filter out the primary key attribute from the collection of attributes I was copying to the cloned entity.

Note that typically a better approach would be to setup a reflexive relationship, map attributes through native field mappings, and then use the InitializeFromRequest but this was a quick migration script.

One other thing that could potentially cause this error we've found: if you don't include "RequireNewInstance=true" in your connection string, you may accidentally end up with a cached connection to another org and therefore encounter duplicates if you're performing the same updates against multiple orgs.